# Mysql memory efficiency and type declaration

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, memory

I have heard that in MsSQL/Access databases that if you declare a varchar of length 100, it declares those 100 chars every row, even if there is only one char in that column.

I have two questions about this.
First: is this true? And if yes, does this also work like this in MySQL?

*Why i'm asking this:*

I'm working a lot with mysql, and i came across a table database with 128 longtext-columns. The reasoning behind this was "We cannot be certain how much data gets stored in these columns. sometimes it's 1 char, sometimes thousands." I was wondering if this was the right way storage-wise, or that he has to do some changes.

Comment: What does this even mean?   "it declares those 100 chars every row"?

Comment: It doesn't work like that for MySQL. It allocates as many bytes is needed for the string (say, 30) and then it appends 1 byte at the end that holds the length. I've no idea about the internals of the other 2 systems, but I'd expect it behaves the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, `VARCHAR` is meant for variable length text, while `CHAR` is fixed length. The number parameter is the character limit for the text but VARCHAR only uses up as much space as the actual characters you enter in that row (+ some bytes to store the length used).
2. MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and pretty much all relational databases work the same way with `VARCHAR`. Every column takes up some minimum amount of space in a row but with `VARCHAR` it would be the bytes to store the text + bytes to store the length of the text. No text entered would mean just a 1 or 2 bytes used to save '0' as the length.
3. If you don't know how much text data will be entered, then use `LONGTEXT` in MySQL or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in MS-SQL. This datatype allows you to store an unlimited amount of text efficiently (up to the row size limitations of the database itself). It's just a bigger, unlimited length version of standard `VARCAHR`.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server the answer is no. From the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176089.aspx):

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n
>   defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max
>   indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The
>   storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The
>   ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

It is possible someone was confusing VARCHAR and CHAR.  The CHAR data type requires a fixed amount of storage, based on the maximum allowed size.

**EDIT**

Rereading your question I'm not entirely sure I've followed your meaning.  If you were not referring to the required storage space then please disregard.